# Swift Generics with Any

Tags: ios, swift

I have been playing with generics and have this function which takes an array and checks if it contains a given value...

```
func finder<T:Equatable>(array:[T], valueToFind:T) -> Int? {
    for(index, value) in enumerate(array) {
        if(value == valueToFind) {
            return index
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

If I use it with this test array, it works perfectly and returns the right index.

```
var testArray = ["Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Tiger"]

finder(testArray, "Cat")
```

Similarly it works for this test array of numbers:

```
var testArray = [1, 2]

finder(testArray, 1)
```

However, When I have a test array like this with strings and numbered, (I assume inferred to be type Any, then the function doesn't work and I get a compiler error:

```
var testArray = ["Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Tiger", 2]

finder(testArray, "Cat")
```

**Cannot convert the expression's type 'Int?' to type 'StringLiteralConvertible'**
Why is this?

Comment: Interestingly, even though an error is shown, it still seems to work as you would expect (testing in a playground).

Comment: @jtbandes interesting - It doesn't work for me! I'm on Beta 4.

Comment: Actually, it works if you put the array inline, but what doesn't work for me is saving an array as a variable (without explicitly specifying `Any`)

Comment: @jtbandes, sorry I'm not following! Can you share your code?

Comment: It's just a type error. Your array type is not `Equatable` and the error messages are pretty much unusable right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Any` and `AnyObject` does not conform `Equatable` so they can not passed.As you have define generic as `[T]` and it confirms to `<T:Equatable>` where `T` repersents specific type so `AnyObject` and `Any` is not specific type.

As below code will not show error because `T` is not conforming to `Equatable` and it is valid to pass `[Any]`

```
func finder<T>(array:[T], valueToFind:T) -> Int? {
    for(index, value) in enumerate(array) {
       //code 
       //You can not compare here value == valueToFind .T should be Equatable for comparison
    }
    return nil
}


var testArray = ["Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Tiger",2]  //It will refer as Any

finder(testArray, 2)  //not have any errors and it is asuming `testArray` as `Any`
```

You can also see further analysis as `T` require to be specific type

So you need to give specific type for generics which repersent `T`.As you are passing `T` `valueToFind` as `String` so `array` also needs to be type  of `String` as it shows in error of below two statements.If you pass Int than it will show `'IntegerLiteralConvertible'` error

```
finder<T:Equatable>(array:[T], valueToFind:T) //Here both `T` should be refer to same type either String or Int

var testArray = ["Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Tiger",2]


finder(testArray, "Cat")  //Shows error Cannot convert the expression's type 'Int?' to type 'StringLiteralConvertible'

finder(testArray, 2)  //Shows error Cannot convert the expression's type 'Int?' to type 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'
```

or remove the other parameter now it will show `Equatable` error as it is converting `testArray` to `Any` which does not conform `Equatable` but in this it shows specific error

```
func finder<T:Equatable>(array:[T]) -> Int? {

    return nil
}

var testArray = ["Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Tiger",2]

finder(testArray)  //Shows error Cannot convert the expression's type 'Int?' to type 'Equatable'
```

So in this code it is assuming `testArray` as `Any`